# Excel VBA find next cell if its empty add text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a worksheet with many buttons, If there is date in a field i want it to go to the next line, if there is not i need it to return a N/A or a 0.00. my code works if i just do this with one cell but if i attempt to add another it either won't return the n/a or it will add the n/a and the data in the cell i want to copy over (this is for the c2 data)

```
Sub Button55_Click()
Dim M As Worksheet
    Set MM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dialer")
            If MM.Range("A2").Value = "" Then Response = MsgBox("Member Number is Blank", vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
                      If Response = vbOK Then Exit Sub
Dim K As Worksheet
    Set KK = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dialer")
            If KK.Range("B2").Value = "" Then Response = MsgBox("Balance Cured is Blank do you Wish to Continue?", vbYesNo + vbCritical)
                      If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
                      If Response = vbYes Then
                         
        Dim C As Range
        Set C = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)
        If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then Set C = C.Offset(1)
        
        Dim P As Range
        Set P = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)
        If Len(P.Value) > 0 Then Set P = P.Offset(1)
        P.Value = "N/A"
        End If
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet")
    
    Dim NextFreeCell As Range 'Range(C)'
    Set NextFreeCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    
        NextFreeCell.Value = "Deceased"
    Dim R As Range
        Set R = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        If Len(R.Value) > 0 Then Set R = R.Offset(1)
        R.Value = Worksheets("Dialer").Range("a2").Value
        
    Dim B As Range
        Set B = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)
        If Len(B.Value) > 0 Then Set B = B.Offset(1)
        B.Value = Worksheets("Dialer").Range("B2").Value
        
    Dim X As Range
        Set X = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)
        If Len(X.Value) > 0 Then Set X = X.Offset(1)
        X.Value = Date
        
    Dim J As Range
        Set J = Worksheets("Worksheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)
        If Len(J.Value) > 0 Then Set J = J.Offset(1)
        J.Value = Worksheets("Dialer").Range("C2").Value
        

        
    
    
    Range("A2").ClearContents
    Range("B2").ClearContents
    Range("C2").ClearContents
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can understand your intention, you want to take the values from the `Dialer!A2:C2`  range, which are `{Member Number |Balance Cured |Empty or any value}`, form a row like `{Member Number |Date|“Deceased”|Balance Cured |"N/A" or [C2].Value}` from them and put it in the first empty row on the `Worksheet` ? I'm afraid all this code should be completely rewritten, minor fixes won't make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert your code. I hope I guessed your goal correctly:

```
Sub Button55_Click()
Rem Do not scatter variable declarations throughout the procedure code,
Rem collect them all in one place, at the beginning:
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rSourceRange As Range
Dim aSourceData As Variant, aResultData(0, 4) As Variant
Dim lastNonEmptyCell As Range
Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long

Rem Variable values that will not change later, calculate immediately
Rem and then just use (don't calculate it every time)
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dialer")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet")
    Set rSourceRange = wsSource.Range("A2:C2")
    aSourceData = rSourceRange.Value
    
Rem Populate the array of results sequentially, element by element -
Rem jumps 4, 5, then 3, 1, 2, and again 4 and 5 makes the code very difficult to read!
    aResultData(0, 0) = aSourceData(1, 1)
    If IsEmpty(aSourceData(1, 1)) Then
Rem If vbOKOnly is used in MSGBOX(), then it is useless to check whether the function will return vbOK
        Call MsgBox("Member Number is Blank", vbOKOnly + vbCritical)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    aResultData(0, 1) = Date
    aResultData(0, 2) = "Deceased"
    aResultData(0, 3) = aSourceData(1, 2)
    If IsEmpty(aSourceData(1, 2)) Then
        If MsgBox("Balance Cured is Blank do you Wish to Continue?", vbYesNo + vbCritical) = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            aResultData(0, 3) = "N/A"
        End If
    End If
    aResultData(0, 4) = aSourceData(1, 3)
    If IsEmpty(aSourceData(1, 3)) Then aResultData(0, 4) = "N/A"
Rem .End(xlUp) is a good way to find the last cell in one column.
Rem But if you are looking for the last ROW on the sheet, then it is better to use another way:
    Set lastNonEmptyCell = wsTarget.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If lastNonEmptyCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstEmptyRow = 1
    Else
        FirstEmptyRow = lastNonEmptyCell.Row + 1
    End If
Rem Try not to read and write cells one at a time,
Rem read and write in whole ranges - this is much more efficient:
    wsTarget.Range("A" & FirstEmptyRow & ":E" & FirstEmptyRow).Value2 = aResultData
Rem For dates to display correctly, set the cell to the correct date format:
    wsTarget.Range("B" & FirstEmptyRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
Rem And clear the whole range in one go:
    rSourceRange.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: @JohnHopper *I also hope that you don't just use this procedure, but read the comments in the code that I left specifically for you to explain why the code posted in your question is bad.*

Comment: Thank you so much!! i am all self taught and i really appreciate the comments explaining where i went wrong